# finding/verifying big O notation of recursive function

Tags: recursion, big-o

**The Function**:

function multiply(x, y)

if y = 0:

  return 0

z = multiply(x, ⎣y/2⎦)

if y is even: 

  return 2z

else:

  return x + 2z

**The Question**:

"If the input is an m-bit number x and an n-bit number y, how long does it take to multiply x and y?"

**My Logic**:

It takes **n** recursive calls to get to the base case*. It takes **n** steps to back out of each function call and either do 2z or x + 2z.

Therefore, it takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.

Is this right?

I was told it should be O(mn), but I don't believe it. If I'm wrong, please explain why.

*since it divides y by 2 repeatedly until it gets to the base case, the number of recursive calls is based on the closest power of 2 below the value of y. Since binary is just bits in the power of 2, the n-bits of y is equal to the number of recursive calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases when you will always perform calculation of the 'x + 2z' in any recursive call except last case (when y will be 0). For example, multiply(5, 31) and etc.
So I think that main thing is in '+' operation. When numbers are very big, it will not take a 1 machine step to perform adding. As a result we have to calculate how much machine steps we have to spend for adding x number (which is m bits long) to another one. Result is O(m) steps.
That's why answer is O(mn).

P.S. '2z' will take a static number of steps because we can add 0 to the end of number and get the result. Imagine that number is very big and we store every bit as an element of array. So we can push 0 to the end of array and we will have the result of operation '2z'.